# Case query is not working 

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL and any help would be welcomed.

Can anyone advise on the best approach for the creating the following query.

```
   _hs_eb_code1 = 'bf', then set format = _hs_eb_det1
   _hs_eb_code# = 'bf', then set format = _hs_eb_det#

Repeat until _hs_eb_code# (1-9),
```

However if the character length of `_hs_eb_det1` exceeds 100 characters, then prefix with `'*'`. In addition _hs_eb_code1 = 'bf' is one, while _hs_eb_det1 will provide many in terms of results.

So far, I can use case query to check for the first part, then build another query. I get lost.

The query:

```
 SELECT CASE 
    WHEN LEN(FORMAT) < 100 THEN LEFT(FORMAT,100)
    ELSE '*'+FORMAT 
 END AS FORMAT
FROM (SELECT CASE

           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE1 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT  WHERE   _HS_EB_CODE1 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET1 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE2 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE2 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET2
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE3 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE3 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET3     
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE4 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE4 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET4
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE5 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE5 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET5
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE6 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE6 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET6
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE7 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE7 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET7
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE8 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE8 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET8
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE9 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE  _HS_EB_CODE9 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET9
END ) AS FORMAT
    FROM DBO.SRC_TBM_BILLGRP
```

But I have a problem in that  the query has one to many, therefore fails to work.
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE1 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT  WHERE   _HS_EB_CODE1 = 'BF') THEN _HS_EB_DET1

Answer (score 2):

```
select case when len(format) > 100 then left(format, 100) + '*' else format end as format from
(select case 'bf' when _hs_eb_code1 then _hs_eb_det1
              when _hs_eb_code2 then _hs_eb_det2
              when _hs_eb_code3 then _hs_eb_det3
              when _hs_eb_code4 then _hs_eb_det4
              when _hs_eb_code5 then _hs_eb_det5
              when _hs_eb_code6 then _hs_eb_det6
              when _hs_eb_code7 then _hs_eb_det7
              when _hs_eb_code8 then _hs_eb_det8
              when _hs_eb_code9 then _hs_eb_det9
              end) as format
    from <yourtable>) a
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, already got the case bit down. The issue is the next bit - If _hs_eb_det#  exceeds 100 character length then prefix with '*'. Unsure how to create query

Comment: The second part of the query is the issue: SELECT CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT _HS_EB_CODE1 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE1 = 'BF') THEN 
(SELECT _HS_EB_DET1 FROM DBO.SRC_TBM_BILLGRP WHERE _HS_EB_DET1 IS NOT NULL AND _HS_EB_DET1 <> '')
 END 
FROM DBO.SRC_TBM_BILLGRP. I need a specify a many to many, since the exists only works with 1 to 1.

Comment: @PeleO I am sorry, I do not understand the question from that bit of code.

Comment: The problem is that we have a 1 to many resultset, which does not work. So SELECT _HS_EB_CODE1 FROM DBO.SRC_HBL_CLNT_CAT WHERE _HS_EB_CODE1 = 'BF' returns back 1 result. While SELECT _HS_EB_DET1 FROM DBO.SRC_TBM_BILLGRP WHERE _HS_EB_DET1 IS NOT NULL AND _HS_EB_DET1 <> '' returns back many rows of data.